# XSLT, copy node but not the data in the node

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to be able to copy a node in xml, but not the data itself.

Example:

```
<Report>   
    <PaymentAccountInfo>     
        <AccountName>Demo Disbursement Account</AccountName>
    </PaymentAccountInfo>
</Report>
```

This would need to be just

```
<Report>
    <PaymentAccountInfo>
        <AcocuntName></AccountName>
    </PaymentAccountInfo>
</Report>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Just the usual method of copying all xml nodes.  Only with the select of the apply-templates as 'node()' only.  Been searching the web for a clue and have not found anything so far.

Comment: ok, so why the down tick for the question??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version='1.0'
    xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>

<xsl:output method="xml" 
    indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="* | @*"/>
        <!--
        to also display text, change this line to
        <xsl:apply-templates select="* | @* | text()"/>
        -->
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name(.)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Just the usual method of copying all xml nodes. Only with the select of the apply-templates as 'node()' only

So your current XSLT is (more or less)

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You need to add an additional template to suppress text nodes within `AccountName` elements

```
  <xsl:template match="AccountName/text()" />
```

This will produce the desired

```
<Report>   
    <PaymentAccountInfo>     
        <AccountName/>
    </PaymentAccountInfo>
</Report>
```

If you want to remove *all* text nodes rather than just those inside `AccountName` (which will also remove the indentation as it squashes whitespace-only nodes), just use `match="text()"` instead of `match="AccountName/text()"`

Answer (score 0):

This modified identity transform will do what you want. It has a special template for the unique processing of `AccountName` elements, which outputs only the tags of the element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="AccountName">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Report>   
  <PaymentAccountInfo>     
    <AccountName/>
  </PaymentAccountInfo>
</Report>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the text content from all elements, you can modify the [identity transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying) by replacing `node()` with `*`.

This will also strip out comments and processing instructions though, so either:

- add `comment()` and/or `processing-instruction()` to `*` (`*|comment()|processing-instruction()`)

or

- leave the identity transform alone and add the template `<xsl:template match="text()"/>`.

Example:

**XML Input**

```
<Report>   
    <PaymentAccountInfo>     
        <AccountName>Demo Disbursement Account</AccountName>
    </PaymentAccountInfo>
</Report>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<Report>
   <PaymentAccountInfo>
      <AccountName/>
   </PaymentAccountInfo>
</Report>
```